# Error when trying to get section using XYZ pcmsim = (XYZ)appConfig.GetSection("XYZ");

Tags: c#, config

Need explanation of Configuration Section Type on following MSDN link [Configuration Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationproperty?view=netframework-4.8)

Having issue with following section

```
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="CustomSection" type="ConfigurationPropertyExample.CustomSection, ConfigurationPropertyExample" 
          allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" 
          restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
      </configSections>
      <CustomSection fileName="override.txt" alias="alias.txt" 
        maxUsers="1000" maxIdleTime="00:05:00" />
    </configuration>
```

The Section name has a type.  I need to know what I should use for both the name before and after the comma.  I opened solution explorer and viewed the references for my assembly.  I assume the references and the type must match.  My application and many nested classes and the MSDN webpage doesn't give good info on how to reference an object in nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

The value given for the `type` attribute represents the **assembly-qualified name** of the `CustomSection` type.

From the [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.8)

> The assembly-qualified name of a type consists of the type name,
>   including its namespace, followed by a comma, followed by the display
>   name of the assembly.

`ConfigurationPropertyExample.CustomSection, ConfigurationPropertyExample` from left to right consists of

1. the namespace: `ConfigurationPropertyExample`
2. the type/class name: `CustomSection`
3. the displayname of the assembly containing the `CustomType` type: `ConfigurationPropertyExample`
   *(Most of the time this will be the name of the assembly file without the (.dll or .exe) file extension.)*

---

Use the `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` property to retrieve a types assembly-qualified name.

```
var assemblyQualifiedName = typeof(CustomSection).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

The returned value might include more than just the namespace, class and assembly,
like version, culture and public key token (see the [specifying assembly names documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names#specifying-assembly-names)), eg.

`ConfigurationPropertyExample.CustomSection, ConfigurationPropertyExample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Most of the time it is not necessary to include these last ones in a configuration `type` definition, unless you are making use of [strong-named assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies).

---

In case of nested classes, a plus sign (`+`) will precede the nested class in the assembly-qualified name.

If the `CustomSection` class was defined as a nested class of a class `Settings`, then its assembly-qualified name would be `ConfigurationPropertyExample.Settings+CustomSection, ConfigurationPropertyExample`.

```
namespace ConfigurationPropertyExample
{
    public class Settings
    {  
        public sealed class CustomSection : ConfigurationSection
        {
            // ...
        }       
    } 
}
```